# Druid error when using distinct count in post aggregation

Tags: count, druid

I am trying to get average value, for that, I've got longSum and distinctCount and using the arithmetic function to get the value. However, druid fails with 500 Error as I am using distinctCount in arithmetics.

Any other value  (min, sum, count) works well.
The value for distinct count itself works and I able to get output in the table.

```
"aggregations": [
    {
        "fieldNames": [
            "unifiedProjectId"
        ],
        "name": "count_distinct__unifiedProject",
        "type": "cardinality"
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "executionDurationInMinutesPerSite",
        "name": "sum__executionDurationInMinutesPerSite",
        "type": "doubleSum"
    }
]


"postAggregations": [
    {
        "fields": [
            {
                "fieldName": "sum__executionDurationInMinutesPerSite",
                "name": "sum__executionDurationInMinutesPerSite",
                "type": "fieldAccess"
            },
            {
                "fieldName": "count_distinct__unifiedProject",
                "name": "count_distinct__unifiedProject",
                "type": "fieldAccess"
            }
        ],
        "fn": "/",
        "name": "avg_execution_time_per_project",
        "type": "arithmetic"
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in Druid's Broker logs when you get 500? 
Can you show the full query? Will it work if you replace `count_distinct__unifiedProject` with `sum__executionDurationInMinutesPerSite` in you postAggregation?(this will obviously lead to a field full of `1`s, but this is to isolate the issue and check whether it actually caused by `cardinality` aggregation and not something else.

Comment: It works with any other aggregation type, sum, count, min, max, etc.